# Error calling JavaScript based Stored Procedure in Snowflake

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to read an API using JavaScript. Since Snowflake Stored Procedures are JavaScript based, I tried the following Stored Procedure.

```
create or replace procedure myschema.stproc1()
    returns string
    language javascript
    as
    $$
        // Create a request variable and assign a new XMLHttpRequest object to it.
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        
        // Open a new connection, using the GET request on the URL endpoint
        request.open('GET', 'https://myappi.application.com/external/api/rest/v2/rooms/?includeCancelled=true&includePastReservations=true&limit=500', true);
        
        request.onload = function () {
          // Begin accessing JSON data here
        }
        
        // Send request
        request.send();
    $$
    ;
```

And, I am getting the below error when trying to call the Stored Procedure:

> JavaScript execution error: Uncaught ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is
> not defined in STPROC1 at ' var request = new XMLHttpRequest();'
> position 22 stackstrace: STPROC1 line: 3

I am fairly new to both JavaScript and Procedures in Snowflake. So, couldn't figure out what the issue is. I am using this code based out of reference from [here](https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-connect-to-an-api-with-javascript/).

Comment: You cannot call things outside of Snowflake. XMLHttpRequest is doing a call outside Snowflake, but that is not allowed. Check the available functionality of Javascript API: **https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html**

Comment: Thanks @Sergiu! I've gone through this earlier and didn't quite understand. So, is it not possible to read an API from Snowflake?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Sergiu's comment:

If you want to call an external API from within Snowflake, you need to go through an external function setup:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-introduction.html

For the simplest deploy, use the Serverless plugin:

- https://github.com/starschema/serverless-snowflake-external-function-plugin

Comment: Felipe - thanks for this information. I am confused a little bit here. Based on what I understood, I should be creating an API INTEGRATION and then create EXTERNAL FUNCTION. Is that correct? If so, for the API INTEGRATION, should I have SCIM enabled for my Snowflake instance?